# Gnuplot xrange not really a range?

Tags: gnuplot

I try to make a plot on gnuplot which has no real range order on x-axis.

```
--------------------->
1 4 2 20 17 12 10 8
```

It's therefore not a real function as you would interpret it with math knowledge, but it has some sort of index on its x-axis which has no numbering order and runs from 1-20 but 20 could be the first, or in the middle.. everything may be mixed..
hope you understand what I mean cause I am hoping gnuplot can handle that.

maybe i can write my data file so that point 2 contains the data that should be there on the y-axis and just move the labels around on x-axis?

Comment: Solution is using xticlabels and add an extra column in the data file.

ie

#xdata ydata label
0 2 1
1 3 14
2 10 0
3 8 20
etc.

command:

    plot "data.dat" using 1:2:xticlabels(3) with lp"

Comment: If you answered your own question with the comment above, post it as an answer instead, and not a comment.

Comment: @Woltan yes I will, but with a rep < 100 I will just have to wait until I am able to after 8 hours or so. therefore I just posted it to let everybody know not to care about it anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is using xticlabels and add an extra column in the data file. 
ie

```
#xdata ydata label 
0 2 1 
1 3 14
2 10 0 
3 8 20 
etc. 

command: plot "data.dat" using 1:2:xticlabels(3) with lp"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could e.g. write a datafile "data" containing such values

```
1     1.5
4     2
2     3.2
20    2.2
17    0.4
12    4.3
```

The second column are the "y-values", the first column the labels of the x-axis (xtics)

now try to plot this data with:

```
plot './data' u 2:xticlabel(1)
```

is that what you want?