# Gnuplot: Defining an x axis based on the order of my values

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data

```
20,10.00
21,10.00
22,10.00
23,09.00
00,10.00
01,10.00
...
```

I want to graph the first value on the x axis and the second value on the y axis. I want the y axis to be autoset but I want the x axis to follow in line with my data eg. `20, 21, ..., 0, 1...`  instead of `0, 1, ..., 23`

I thought I would do this with xticlabels, stating `plot "filename" using xticlabels(1):2` or, as inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922936/gnuplot-xrange-not-really-a-range?rq=1), `1:2:xticlabels(1)`. Neither has the desired effect. What am I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must use `xticlabels` to add individual labels. But now you must still specify some value for the x-axis. If you know, that the rows all have the same spacing, then use the zeroth column as x-value:

```
plot "filename" using 0:2:xticlabels(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For my specific case, setting xrange [23:0] will suffice. However, this is not dynamic as it does not apply in the case of unordered values, so I am still curious of how the problem would otherwise be solved.